# what is the proper way deploy maven java adapter

Tags: java, maven, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli

[this](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/developing-adapters/) tutorial to deploy adapter with jar file

- File → Import... → Maven → Existing Maven Projects.(java adapter  create by cli use this comment "mfpdev adapter create")
- add two  jar file from the  lib folder
- Select Run → Run Configurations..., right-click on Maven Build and select New.

  - Provide a Name: "Maven deploy".
  - Set as a Goal: "adapter:deploy".

but run not enable . what am i missing?
[image]

**project structure :**

[image]

**Run As → Maven install** not found for  build an adapter

[image]

and used flowing command to **FileUploadAdapter** java adapter by CLI

> mfpdev adapter create 
>    cd FileUploadAdapter/
>    mfpdev adapter build
>    mfpdev adapter deploy

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the step that you need to *build* the adapter.
There is nothing to deploy if you did not build it yet.

> **Building an adapter**
>   To build an adapter, right-click on the adapter folder and select Run As → Maven install.

Comment: **Run As → Maven install** not found for build an adapter

Comment: please see my Update

Comment: You need to create the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the screenshots you have posted, you need to do 2 things to get this working:

1) When creating a Maven run configuration, you need to specify the base directory. Choose your maven project here . ie, "FileUploadAdapter".

2) Once this is done, you need to right click the maven project - ie, the FileUploadAdapter to perform Run As -> Maven deploy. As per the screenshot you are trying to perform Run As on the "target" folder of the maven project. This will not give you any options.